# Order duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm running the following query;

```
SELECT  Column 1, COUNT(*) "TOTAL LINES",
        Column 2

FROM TABLE
WHERE Column 3 > 0
GROUP BY Column 1, Column 2
HAVING COUNT(Column 1) > 1
ORDER BY Column 2
```

My results are as follows;

`Column 1 TOTAL LINES Column 2
    001           2      123456  <-- DUPLICATE
    002           2      123456  <-- DUPLICATE
    001           5      891011
    002           2      121314
    001           6      151617    <-- DUPLICATE
    002           2      151617    <-- DUPLICATE
    002           2      181920
    001           2      212223`

Comment: Please tell us what is not working and what is expected. and format a little

Comment: Is there a question there? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This query is functioning as designed. You're asking for counts for each of the distinct values of the combination of `Column 1` and `Column 2`, and MySQL is dutifully presenting what you asked.

You do have two lines with the `Column 2` value 151617. But those lines differ from each other in the values of `Column 1`. Therefore, they are not duplicates.